# Table in LaTeX: Align the table in single column using the two column template

Tags: latex, tabular, pdflatex

I am working on the LaTeX overleaf. I am using the IEEE access template which is two column. I have to fix my table in a single column. I have to fix the table where its place. I have used `\FloatBarrier` for this. `\FloatBarrier` has fixed the table on its place but the table is covering the text. I have applied all the techniques like using `Table*`,`!htbp`, `\FloatBarrier` and many more. I will very thankful to solve this issue.

```
\FloatBarrier
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\caption{Car Database}
\label{table:Car_DB}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\toprule
\textbf{Car\_ID}    & \textbf{Car\_Name}    & \textbf{Car\_Number} &\textbf{Owner\_Name}  &\textbf{Owner\_ID} \\
\midrule
C1      &Suzuki Mehran  &RIZ 3725  &Bilal Khalid  &34512-4520645-5\\
C2      &mazda  &MN 3909  &Usman Bhatti  &32103-9963008-2\\
C2      &Toyotta Carolla    &LEL 06 4520  &Ali Haider  &12345-1529307-7\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: The result of this code is like this]

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest reducing the column headers since your `\caption` already mentions items will be related/represent cars. That is, remove the `Car` prefix. Then you can also reduce the `\tabcolsep` inserted between each column using

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.7\tabcolsep}
```

The above command reduces `\tabcolsep` by 30%. Here's a display of the end result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Car Database}
  \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Car\_ID}    & \textbf{Car\_Name}    & \textbf{Car\_Number} &\textbf{Owner\_Name}  &\textbf{Owner\_ID} \\
    \midrule
    C1 & Suzuki Mehran   & RIZ 3725    & Bilal Khalid & 34512-4520645-5 \\
    C2 & Mazda           & MN 3909     & Usman Bhatti & 32103-9963008-2 \\
    C3 & Toyotta Carolla & LEL 06 4520 & Ali Haider   & 12345-1529307-7 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Car Database}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.7\tabcolsep}% Shrink \tabcolsep by 30%
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ *{5}{c} }
    \toprule
    \textbf{ID} & \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Number} & \textbf{Owner name} & \textbf{Owner ID} \\
    \midrule
    C1 & Suzuki Mehran   & RIZ 3725    & Bilal Khalid & 34512-4520645-5 \\
    C2 & Mazda           & MN 3909     & Usman Bhatti & 32103-9963008-2 \\
    C3 & Toyotta Carolla & LEL 06 4520 & Ali Haider   & 12345-1529307-7 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\sloppy % Just for this example
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

More options available from [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/5764)